# What does $b$ does not divide $a$ mean?

Tags: divisibility

Given a statement like $b$ divides $a$ means there exists some integer $k$ such that $a = b\cdot k$, does that mean if $b$ does not divide $a$, then there are integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a = q\cdot b +r$ for $0<r<b$ according to the division algorithm?

Am I assuming too much here?

EDIT: Let me also clarify that I am assuming $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and both are positive.

Comment: Yes, what you say is a correct interpretation of "$b$ does not divide $a$" *for integers $a$ and $b$*.  You could also have phrased it other ways such as $a\not\equiv 0\pmod{b}$, $a$ is not a multiple of $b$, there does not exist any $k$ such that $a=bk$, for all integers $k$ one has $a\neq bk$, etc...

Comment: Depends. Are $a$ and $b$ integers and is $b$ positive?

Comment: Yes, $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b$ is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There's a simpler representation.

To say $b$ does not divide $a$ means that $b$ is not a factor of $a$. That is, if you try to do the division, you'll have leftovers - the remainder $r$.

Answer (score 1):

What you've said is true. That said, depending on what class you're taking (I assume this is for a class), you might need to prove that $r$ can be chosen such that $0 < r < b$, and that the existence of such an $r$ implies that $b\nmid a$ (it depends how detailed you're expected to be).

Comment: I am using this fact to prove a different statement. What I would like to show is that if the order of an element b, does not divide the order of an element a, then the order of a*b is larger than the order of a. I just wanted to get the context behind "does not divide" correct.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Consider the case $b=-5$ and $a=9$. Then we say $b\nmid a$ because there is no integer $k$ with $a=bk$. But you cannot find $q,r$ with $a=qb+r$ and $0<r<b$, simply because the second condition cannot be fulfilled.

Comment: Because this is actually about orders of elements within an abelian group G, it is assumed that $b$ and $a$ are both positive integers.